# Image in UISegmented Control not being rendered

Tags: ios, swift, image, uisegmentedcontrol

In my UISegmented Control, I have set images for segment indices 0 and 1. However, the images are appearing as boxes (as shown in the image). However, when I check my Assets, the image can be seen. What could be the possible reason for this?

[image: image not rendering in uisegmented control]

EDIT:
Testing with different images, what I have found is that if the image is multi colored, then its not being rendered. Otherwise, it shows up with specified tint color. If this is the reason, is it solvable?

Comment: Can I first ask why you are using images and not just setting tint colors for the various controls?

Comment: The app’s design requires image and text in the segmentcontrol. Since it’s not possible to have both of them at the same time so I created images as per the requirement to be displayed in the segmentcontrol.

Comment: Suggestion but what about going to your image in your `assets.xcassets` file and select image, under file inspector on right hand side try checking the box that says `Render as Template Image` Also check out [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624127-resizableimage) function and play around with the top and bottom cap insets when settin background image

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem as well

Answer (score 2):

Following @NSGangster's suggestion, I tried the render options in the image's attribute inspector. Selecting the render option -> "Original Image" solved this problem. Thanks @NSGangster.